# '[WRN]' C1005: Closure Compiler Warning (Parse error. extra visibility tag) -- compression-input:231247:7 fix?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

While running C:\Sencha\Cmd\6.6.0.13\sencha.exe app build for production I came across this warning message:

```
[WRN] C1005: Closure Compiler Warning (Parse error. extra visibility tag) -- compression-input:231267:7
```

I am new to extjs and I am not sure from where this warning message is being thrown or how to correct it. Any information about this warning message would be helpful thank you!

```
Sencha Cmd v6.6.0.13
[INF] Using GPL version of Ext JS version 6.2.0.981 from D:\.......
[INF] The implications of using GPL version can be found here (http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing).
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default (production environment)
[INF] Loading compiler context
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Processing data with CmdJavascriptCompressor
[INF] JavaScript input level is NEXT and output level is ES5
[WRN] C1005: Closure Compiler Warning (Parse error. extra visibility tag) -- compression-input:231267:7
```

I expect to have no warning messages when compiling.

Comment: First Delete `/Users/foo/bin/Sencha/` and re-installed CMD again. And try.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I got a similar error with ExtJs 7.6.0: `[WRN] C1005: Closure Compiler Warning (Parse error. name not recognized due to syntax error.) -- compression-input:290:12`. What did you end up doing?